# Reuse hashmaps in array

Tags: java, performance

I am holding an array of hashmaps, I want to gain maximum performance and memory usage so I would like to resue the hashmaps inside an array.

So when there is a hashmap in the array that is not needed any more and I want to add new hashmap to the array I just clear the hashmap and use put() to add new values.

I also need to copy back values when I retireve hashmap from array.

I am not sure if this is better than creating `new HashMap()` every time.
What is better?

**UPDATE**

need to cycle about 50 milions of hashmaps, each hash map has about 10 key-value pairs. If size of the array 20,000 I need just 20,000 hashmaps instead of 50 milions new hashmaps()

Comment: Unless you tell what you operations you will do on your data/arrays/hashmaps/whatever, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: So you are asking us to *guess* the code you're going to write, then to *guess* the data you're going to feed into it, and finally to profile the hypothetical code by thought experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful with this approach. Although it may be better performance-wise to recycle objects, you may get into trouble by modifying the same reference several times, as illustrated in the following example:

```
public class A {
    public int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         A a = new A();
         a.counter = 5;
         A b = a; // I want to save a into b and then recycle a for other purposes
         a.counter = 10; // now b.counter is also 10
    }
}
```

I'm sure you got the point, however if you are not copying around references to HashMaps from the array, then it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter. Premature optimization. Come back when you have profiler results telling you where you're *actually* spending most memory or CPU cycles

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely unclear why re-using maps in this manner would improve performance and/or memory usage. For all we know, it might make no difference, or might have the opposite effect.

You should do whatever results in the most readable code, then profile, and finally optimize the parts of the code that the profiler highlights as bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you will not feel any difference.

Typically number of map entries is MUCH higher than number of map objects. When you populate map you create instance of `Map.Entry` per entry. This is relatively light-weight object but anyway you invoke `new`. The map itself without data is lightweight too, so you will not get any benefits with these tricks unless your map is supposed to hold 1-2 entries.

Bottom line.
Forget about pre-mature optimization. Implement your application. If you have performance problems profile the application, find bottle necks and fix them. I can 99% guarantee you that the bottleneck will never be in `new HashMap()` call.

Comment: I'll tell you this: I need to cycle about 50 milions of hashmaps, each hash map has about 10 pairs. If the array size 20,000 I need just 20,000 hashmaps instead of 50 milions new hashmaps()

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an Object pool kind of thing, where you get an object(in your case, its HashMap) from the object pool, perform your operations, and if that Object is no longer needed you put it back in the pool.

check for Object pool design pattern, for further reference check this link :

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that most of the objects are Map.Entry objects in the HashMap. While you can recycle the HashMap itself (and its array) these are only a small portion of the objects.  One way around this is to use FastMap from javolution which recycles everything and has support for managing the lifecycle (its designed to minimise garbage this way)

I suspect the most efficient way is to use an EnumMap is possible (if you have known key attributes) or POJOs even if most fields are not used.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with reusing `HashMap`s.

- Even if the key and value data were to take no memory (shared from other places), the `Map.Entry` objects would dominate memory usage but not be reused (unless you did something a bit special).
- Because of generational GC, generally having old objects point to new is expensive (and relatively difficult to see what's going on). Might not be an issue if you are keeping millions of these.
- More complicated code is more difficult to optimise. So keep it simple, and then do the big optimisations, which probably involve changing the data structures.